# Speech recognition (SVM) different signal lengths

Tags: machine-learning, svm, speech-recognition

I am developing a small project on speech recognition, the idea is to classify sound sources by Support Vector Machines. My dataset consists on 45 signals, however, they all have different lengths, therefore, the features that I want to use, spectrograms and cepstrogram (I want to perform image recognition with them), have different lengths.

My questions are:

- How should I use my features? Is it possible to use different length vectors? (considering each spectrogram as a vector).
- Should I sum horizontally the spectrogram in order to have the same length for all the vectors (Which would be the vertical dimension).
- Should I take some statistics as features such as variance, mean, etc..

I am beginner in machine learning, I apologise if the question is very basic. Thank you.

This project is inspired by:

https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/10/acoustic-detection-of-humpback-whales.html?utm_campaign=The+Batch&utm_medium=email&_hsmi=87523675&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-_RDZ6yQxRIXaYszorX89TPZBykHQl5bIny7AOpg1BvpGReVZ6qBobeFFjWZ0u1GmCE5GkY&utm_content=87523675&utm_source=hs_email&m=1

Answer (score 0):

I think a common approach is a windowed approach where you process fixed length sub vectors of your vector and 'slide' the window across. You may have to output some sort of confidence score since during silence or between words it may output nonsense.

[Heres an introduction on windowing.](https://wiki.aalto.fi/display/ITSP/Windowing)